# All my music needs to be downloaded again?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, music.app

I went to play some music on my iPhone (iOS 7) but whenever I tap a track to play it just greys out and a little circle with a stop icon appears next to it (download indicator?).

Any idea why this is or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Yes, your music needs to be redownloaded. You might want to go into your iTunes purchased and download your songs that way.

Comment: Also you could sync with iTunes.

Comment: When it starts downloading, another, thicker line should start running clockwise around the inside of the red circle. (Just like in the App Store, when you are downloading an app.) Does this occur?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the music on your computer, connect to iTunes and sync
again. If this appears, you should download all music from iCloud.